# Creating and returning Observable from Angular 2

Tags: angular

I have a http helper which helps for all http calls in apiservices

```
export class HttpClient {
  post(url : string, data : string) : Observable<any> {
     let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
     let options = new RequestOptions( { headers: headers });
     return this.http.post(url, data, options)
                .map(this.getResult)
                .catch(this.handleError);
  }
}
```

And in my services i call the above method for http post call , from component i call the service , which is the best practice for this 3 tier observable return

Consider My component

```
userService.user(userIdObj)
    .subscribe(user=> this.user= user);
```

Consider My UserService

```
 user() {
   return HttpClient.post(url,data);
 }
```

Currently the above is not working , can anyone explain in detail ?

Comment: what are the errors you getting?

Comment: share your code for more clarity or mention the errors.

Comment: not returning data into the controller subscribe success callback, instead goes into error.

Comment: How do you access `HttpClient` in userService?

Comment: is HttpClient an injectable class?

Comment: HttpClient is an injectable class , and registered the httpclient in app provider and access via DI in services.